# ActiveRecord includes and references query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails is using "includes" and "references" to solve N+1 queries, as we all know. However, I came across a problem while I was testing my query today. Here are some models in my rails app.

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :routes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Route < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

As we can see here, we have a nested relation set up. My query is as below:

```
routes = Route.includes(project: :organization).where("organizations.name like ?", "blablabla").references(project: :organization)
```

This query can successfully fetch route records as I expect. However, I also tried:

```
routes = Route.includes(project: :organization).where("organizations.name like ?", "blablabla").references(:projects)
```

and

```
routes = Route.includes(project: :organization).where("organizations.name like ?", "blablabla").references("xxxxxx")
```

Both of these latter two queries work and get the route records that I want. From my understanding, "includes" must work with "references". And "references" means the table we want to join in the query sentences. But it seems like as long as I pass an argument to "references", whatever this argument is, it can work.

From ActiveRecord source code, it looks like that "references" only checks if you have passed table_names or not.

```
def references(*table_names)
  check_if_method_has_arguments!(:references, table_names)
  spawn.references!(*table_names)
end

def references!(*table_names) # :nodoc:
  self.references_values |= table_names
  self
end
```

Can anybody elaborate that how does this "references" work?

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: Includes loads records in two queries - the first loads all the rows from the routes table and then the second is fired when you access the assocation. `references` tells ActiveRecord that you want to reference that table in the first query - usually to filter the rows.

Comment: The reason the query works no matter if you are using `references` or not is that the where clause causes it to be handled by `eager_load` which fires a single query. This article explains it better then I can https://medium.com/@gandhi.nikita20/joins-vs-includes-vs-preload-vs-eagerload-d5ace03031e0

Comment: It's Rails 6.0.3.4

Comment: @max Thanks max, I think this article answers my question perfectly. But I am wondering, since "includes" plus "where" can do the job, why "references" will be required?

Answer (score -1):

Since you're calling `includes` it is already joining those tables. You need `references` if you use `joins` to join the tables. You could potentially make your query more performant if you use `joins` and `references` instead of includes. It depends on if you're using the `project` or `organization` in the view/response.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `includes` will usually load records and the included associations in two different queries. `references` tells rails you need to explicitly join the table to filter the rows in the first query. There is absolutely no point whatsoever in using references with `.joins` as joins will join in a single query. https://medium.com/@gandhi.nikita20/joins-vs-includes-vs-preload-vs-eagerload-d5ace03031e0

Comment: You’re right. I was off about needing joins. References is if you don’t use joins.